# Change Path Color at Specified Points (to Tricolor Trefoil Knot)

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-knots

I am currently teaching myself Knot Theory and am looking to draw related diagrams using Ti*k*Z. Using the `knots` library and a `foreach` loop, I have written a pretty solid code for drawing a monocolor trefoil knot:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{knot}[
        clip width=5,
        consider self intersections
    ]
        \strand[red,thick] (90:1)
            \foreach \x in {1,2,3} {
                to [bend left=117,looseness=1.9] ({90+120*\x}:1)
            }
        ;
        \flipcrossings{1,3}
    \end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This yields the following image.

[image]

However, I would like to color each uninterrupted segment (3 total) a different color, as in my textbook (note that I am not looking to do the double lines, just the variation from white to grey to black [or colors of my choice, preferably]):

[image]

So far, I have looked into the `decorations` library, `dashed` lines, and more recommendations from this site and others, but I have not found the solution anywhere.

In sum, **how can I independently color the different segments of my knot in Ti*k*Z?**

Note that I would like the procedure to be general enough to be applicable to other knots as well.

Comment: Can help you this link at the §7? https://loopspace.mathforge.org/HowDidIDoThat/TeX/Knots/

Comment: @Sebastiano I have seen this link. I am not sure how that code works, though. If you believe that this could be the solution, can you write up an answer explaining it? I'm still rather new to Ti*k*Z, sorry...

Comment: With lot of sincerity I should to read the manual and I'm not very able to give you an answer. Surely there is my +1. My best regards.

Comment: (Sorry - only just seen this.)  The difficulty here is that colours and decorations have to be applied to paths *as a whole*, but the knot library is designed for when we are trying to draw strands as entire paths which cross over each other at possibly unknown places.  So there's a basic tension between the two. I'm not sure of the best way to solve this one.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Yeah, I worried that that was the case. Based on my own toying around, it looks like `knots` obscures parts of a path rather than creating multiple. Do you have any plans to adjust its functioning, possibly as an option? BTW, I did find a rather crude solution in using multiple strands, but I had to manually create a number of the intersections using the `double` feature of Ti*k*Z.

Comment: If your knots are very structured, like the trefoil, to the point where you *know* where the intersections are then you can build your knot around them and not have to use the knot environment at all.  Take a look at Section 3.3 of the knot package documentation.  If that sounds interesting but you're not sure what it would look like, I could whip up an example or two.  Any particular knots you're looking at?

Comment: @AndrewStacey Although I have read the entirety of the documentation, I had not considered using Section 3.3. I implemented an MWE in my KnotNotes repository on GitHub for the 7_4 knot (the diff between my old and new code can be found [here](https://github.com/shadypuck/KnotNotes/commit/97df4fa94356b0997e1acded231e80cc8f69e45c) and the result is displayed in Figure 1.21b of the [PDF](https://github.com/shadypuck/KnotNotes/blob/master/KnotNotes.pdf)). Is this what you were thinking? BTW, thanks for building this tool -- it was tremendously useful throughout my knot exploits.

Comment: @ShadyPuck Yes, that's the idea.  You could post that bit as an answer here.  (That's quite a tome on knot theory that you're building there!)

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thanks! And I posted an answer below.

Comment: I don't know if your project is still ongoing, but if so then you may be interested in knowing that there's an update to the spath3 library that gives a new way of drawing knots that would be more suited to this question.

Answer (score 1):

[Kudos to @AndrewStacey for suggesting this fix in the comments under the question]

---

A full, simple solution to this problem has not yet been implemented for LaTeX, but the following is a more than adequate approximation.

To begin, consider Section 3.3 of the `knots` library [documentation](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/spath3/knots_doc.pdf), especially the idea of using Ti*k*Z nodes to aid in knot diagrams. The most important passage is quoted below.

> The node `knot crossing` is not meant to be drawn, it is an empty shape...This can be useful for designing curves that enter and exit the crossing gracefully at particular directions. When using this node shape, the crossing itself is easiest to draw by using the `center` anchor for the strands that form the over cross.

Following this guidance, I created the following MWE for the 7_4 knot, modeled after the black and white picture below it and generating the colored picture also below it.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every path/.style={thick},
    every node/.style={knot crossing,inner sep=1.2pt}
]
    \colorlet{rex}{red}
    \colorlet{orx}{orange}
    \colorlet{ylx}{yellow!70!black}

    \node (l) at (-1,0) {};
    \node (c) at (0,0) {};
    \node (r) at (1,0) {};
    \node (lu) at (-0.6,0.6) {};
    \node (lb) at (-0.6,-0.6) {};
    \node (ru) at (0.6,0.6) {};
    \node (rb) at (0.6,-0.6) {};

    \draw [orx] (lb)
        to [out=-50,in=-130] (rb.center)
        to [out=50,in=-120] (r)
    ;
    \draw [rex] (r)
        to [out=60,in=35,out looseness=2.5] (ru.center)
        to [out=-145,in=50] (c)
    ;
    \draw [rex] (c)
        to [out=-130,in=35] (lb.center)
        to [out=-145,in=-120,looseness=2] (l)
    ;
    \draw [orx] (l)
        to [out=60,in=-130] (lu.center)
        to [out=50,in=130] (ru)
    ;
    \draw [ylx] (ru)
        to [out=-50,in=120] (r.center)
        to [out=-60,in=-35,looseness=2] (rb)
    ;
    \draw [rex] (rb)
        to [out=145,in=-52] (c.center)
        to [out=128,in=-35] (lu)
    ;
    \draw [ylx] (lu)
        to [out=145,in=120,in looseness=2.5] (l.center)
        to [out=-60,in=130] (lb)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image] [image]

Let's begin with the styles defined at the beginning of the `tikzpicture` environment. As a matter of personal preference, I draw my knot diagrams with `thick` paths, so it made sense to define that style globally. Additionally, the `inner sep` node option controls the amount of white space at each crossing (the higher the value, the more white space). Lastly, the `knot crossing` node type is actually not technically necessary (I don't believe), but I figured why not.

Next, I define macros for the three colors that I wish to use. This both makes it easy to change every instance of a particular color should I want to and lets every color (when used later on) be represented by a short, three-letter term. Aesthetic, perhaps, but it does make the code more readable. Note that I chose my color names by taking two letters indicative of the color (e.g., "re" for "red") and concatenating the suffix "-x." I choose "-x" because should I want to have multiple shades of a color, subsequent tones could have "-y" and "-z" suffixes.

For the nodes (which must lie at the crossings of the knot), I initially guessed at appropriate positions and then progressively refined. Note that the names of the nodes are abbreviations of their positions -- from top to bottom in the MWE: left, center, right, left-upper, left-bottom, right-upper, right-bottom. Also note that while it was not necessary here, the `scale` key could be used to shrink or grow the knot.

Now that the invisible, helper parts have been set up, I used seven `draw` macros -- one for each of the seven strands of the knot. Note that using seven instead of one `draw` macro is only necessary because of the multiple colors. Regardless, to create the code, I began at one crossing and worked my way through all of them, following the black and white picture and the instructions from Section 3.3 quoted above and guessing at `in` and `out` angles for the `to` macro. After I had my draft, I progressively refined the angles and added in `looseness` macros as needed (maintaining symmetry throughout) until I was satisfied. Colors were added in last.

Although imperfect in that this method lacks the ease of the `knot` environment adjusted with a multicolor feature, this method creates a non-buggy, procedural rendering of a multicolor knot. Although this is generally true for any diagram, note that to ease the code's creation, a decent sketch of the knot must be made first to locate the crossings' positions.